# how do i loop through rows in excel and set an IF condition "IF $F11=2 then" have new cell=$B11?

Tags: excel, loops, rows

```
Sub CHECKFIX()
      Dim x As Integer
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 
      ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
      NumRows = Range("R2", Range("R66").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
      ' Select cell a1.
      Range("R2").Select
      ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
      For x = 1 To NumRows
         ' Insert your code here.
         ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

***      IF($F11=2,$B11)

      Next
   End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a little more detail to this? if all you want is to be able to make an IF statement evaluate $F11 (specific column, non-specific row) and set $B11, that can be easily done in Excel without VBA. If you really want to use VBA for this what exactly are you wanting to know: how to use a loop of rows? how to setup the if statement?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should take a moment to read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  That will explain the best way to ask your question to get the help you are looking for.

Comment: `If range("F11").value = 2 Then ActiveCell = Range("B11").value` should do the trick.

Comment: my bad guys, you are right